# Teams Guest users cannot bypass the lobby without the organizer, even though "Everyone" is selected in Meeting Options

Tags: entra-id, microsoft-teams

In my personal MS 365 Tenant (Business Basic subscription), when I invite external users to a Teams meeting, they can join the meeting, but only after I, the organizer, join. I would like them to be able to join before I am there (or if I am not there at all). In the Meeting Options, I do have "Everyone" set for the option "Who can bypass the lobby?" Is there some other setting I'm missing to allow external guests to be able to join (in the Azure AD control panel?) the meeting at any time?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because do we have a Teams SE site?

Comment: @Chopper3 there is https://stackoverflow.co/teams, but that's "Stack Overflow for Teams", which is definitely *not* a SE site focused on Microsoft Teams.

Comment: @Chopper3 so how about rescinding your close vote since you are mistaken about there being a dedicated Teams site?

Comment: Also: Love the driveby downvotes

Comment: Have you reviewed this document that explains the policy that needs to be set for this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/who-can-bypass-meeting-lobby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the right option to adjust! The solution is to go to the [Teams Admin Center](https://admin.teams.microsoft.com) -> Meetings -> Meeting Policies -> Manage Policies -> Global (Org-wide default) (or whatever your current appropriate policy is) -> Meeting join & lobby -> All options **On** and **Who can bypass the lobby**: Everyone. Guests no longer need to wait to join until the host arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my own experience, I can say that it's NOT possible to circumvent the "lobby" as a guest user in Teams.

Comment: I know it is possible, as it happens at my work - external accounts to my company can join meetings first.